# Javascript is included twice, because LESS CSS requires assets to be enabled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets, pipeline

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap with **LESS**, and it **requires assets pipeline to be enabled**. But if assets are enabled, then my **CoffeeScript code is included twice** in the browser - once in application.js, and second time within posts.js.

How can I fix this?

Both files contain:

```
$('.slider').each(function() {
    val = $(this).attr('val')
    $(this).slider({
      orientation: 'horizontal',
      range: "min",
      max:100
    });
```

And I'm getting an error in both files: **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'** from Chrome just after

```
$(this).slider({
```

However, if I will now go to posts.js and comment it there, it will pass without errors, and the twin function from application.js will just work.

Comment: You should be more specific. Include your application.js and posts.js code a least.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the pipeline doesn't care whether you have this line in your application.js

```
//= require_tree .
```

together with another line such as:

```
*= require jquery.ui.slider
```

And if jquery.ui.slider.js is under ".", it just includes it twice, because that's what you're telling it to do. And it doesn't really check whether this file is already included.